# Using delegate from different classes

Tags: ios

Having some difficulty getting my delegate to "work".

It works when the ClassA pushes ClassB onto the stack via UINavigationController, but ClassB does not call the delegate method (in ClassA) when ClassB is pushed by a different ClassC.

This method from within ClassA works:

```
- (void)openViewController:(NSString *)title:(int)dataType:(NSArray *)currentData {    
ClassB *nextController = [[ClassB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassBView" bundle:nil];
nextController.delegate = self;
nextController.title = title;
nextController.dataType = dataType;
nextController.currentData = currentData;
nextController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];}
```

How do I get this method, from ClassC, to properly designate ClassA as the delegate for ClassB???

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
ClassB *nextController = [[ClassB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassBView" bundle:nil];
    nextController.delegate = ??????????
    nextController.title = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    nextController.dataType = self.dataType;
    nextController.currentData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.dictionary objectForKey:[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    nextController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];}
```

Appreciate any assistance. Cheers.

Comment: Your question is confusing as you don't make the difference between a `class` and an instance of that class. Please check those notions and edit your question to make it more clear

Comment: Trying be more specific....The ClassB has a specific view that is "pushed" by either ClassA or ClassC. However, whenever there is a change in ClassB, I want it to fire a delegate method within ClassA, regardless of whether it was ClassA or ClassC that "pushed" the view. Easy enough to establish the delegate when "pushing" from ClassA to ClassB, but how do you designate ClassA as the delegate of ClassB from ClassC? ....clear as mud, I am sure....

Comment: In that case, the answer bellow sound pretty reasonable to me. But please, check the difference between a class and the instance of a class

Comment: Thank you again. Foggy brain....I should be saying instance of the class(es), not just class.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like knowing more about the view controller hierarchy in the app would help, but it sounds like you'll need to add a reference to ClassA in ClassC that it could pass on to ClassB. So (in ClassC) `nextController.delegate = self.ClassARef`

Comment: Thanks for your help...still working on the solution and will post it if I get there.